# Calling an oauth api request page from a different page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, oauth

I have a search page. On this search page, I have a text input element. What I'd like is to have the text input element call the database and retrieve the results and display them in an unordered list.

With that being said, the data is being aggregated from an API. I have a page which connects to the api, does a request for the token, then after that request has been processed, it does a subsequent request for the search term and stores the information into the database.

How do I send the request to the api page, store the results in the database, then send back a success result and have the search page then do a database call? I'd like to use jQuery AJAX for this.

I'm using PHP.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 if(isset($_GET['serve'])){ // i added a header call in the php api page when its done adding data to the database. it is -> header("Location: testsearch.php?serve=1");
  echo "finished";  
} else {
  header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/gs/apiconnect.php?synset=Beyonce&start_date=20130301&end_date=20130501");
}
```

This works, but Im a bit hazy on how to implement this for my specific needs (I know that what I did isn't going to work)